Group dragging in PixiJS
I’m developing an application where users can create and drag various shapes. The current functionality allows users to create shapes and drag them individually. However, users can only drag one shape at a time for now.
I want to add functionality similar to Figma, where users can create shapes inside other shapes (parent-child relationship). If the parent shape is selected and dragged, all its child shapes should move along with it.
You can see child and parent shapes
In essence, when the user drags the parent shape, all its child shapes should move together, maintaining their relative positions.
